# Probability of rolling two dies with different possible rewards

Tags: probability

A game comprises of rolling two dies simultaneously for a single turn and giving each player a score based on the numbers they roll. The players are awarded 1 point for rolling a 6 and any other number on the two dies. It also rewards 5 points if a 6 is rolled with a 3. No points are rewards for any other combinations. Find the probabilities of getting a total score of 5 and a total score of 3 in a total of 3 turns.

**My Solution**

I have skipped lots of steps to make this post smaller. Is my solution correct?

Probability of getting 6 = $\frac{1}{6}$

Probability of getting 3 = $\frac{1}{6}$

Probability of getting 1 point in one turn = Probability of getting 6 on one die and any number except 3 on the other die = $\frac{9}{36}$

Probability of getting 5 points in one turn = Probability of getting 6 on one die and 3 on the other die = $\frac{2}{36}$

Probability of getting 0 points in one turn = Probability of not getting 6 on both dies = $\frac{25}{36}$

To get a total score of 3 in three turns, the player must earn 1 point in all three turns, therefore,

P(scoring 3 points in 3 turns) = Probability of getting 1 point in each of the three turns = $\frac{9}{36} \times \frac{9}{36} \times \frac{9}{36}$

To get a total score of 5 in three turns, the player must earn 5 points in exactly one turn and 0 points in other two turns.

P(scoring 5 points in 3 turns) = $3 \times$ Probability of getting 5 point in one turn $\times$ Probability of scoring zero in one turn $\times$ Probability of scoring zero in one turn = $3 \times \frac{2}{36} \times \frac{25}{36} \times \frac{25}{36}$

Comment: Everything looks good.   Grammar tip:  the plural of die is dice (contrary to the usual rules for forming the plural).